# VBA script to create Queries based on entries in an existing table/Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following SQL code:

```sql
SELECT  EverythingCMDB.company
        , COUNT(EverythingCMDB.company) AS People 
FROM    (
         SELECT DISTINCT    EverythingCMDB.MacAddress
                            , EverythingCMDB.company
                            , Monthly.street
                            , Monthly.MacVendor 
         FROM   EverythingCMDB INNER JOIN Monthly ON EverythingCMDB.MacAddress = Monthly.MAC 
         WHERE  Monthly.street ="222 Testing AVE" AND 
                EverythingCMDB.company <> NULL
        )  
GROUP BY EverythingCMDB.company;
```

I also have a query called *AllAddresses*. This query has 1 column containing all distinct addresses from the *Monthly* table.

Is there any way to create a VBA script that creates a query for all the addresses in my above query?

In a sense, the `Monthly.street ="222 Testing AVE"` will be changed in order to create a unique count for each location (*"222 Testing AVE"* will change to *"123 Fake Street"* in the new query, as that is an address in the *AllAddresses* query).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  This doesn't need VBA -- you just need to add the query listing the addresses to the `FROM` list on this query, either with a `JOIN` or a comma, then use the field name containing the addresses in your `WHERE` clause. Here is [related info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nest-a-query-inside-another-query-or-in-an-expression-by-using-a-subquery-a8532322-e42f-4f94-bc38-ace7c182916a)

Comment: Should you be selecting from `SubQuery` rather than `EverythingCMDB`? Your `FROM` argument is aliased as `SubQuery`.

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need say 50+ queries each with different addresses?

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of people per department at each location; each location having its own query. Although it's called EverythingCMDB.company, it should be aliased as department, as that's what it is. This query works perfectly for each location I've done manually, I just need to find a way to automatically create new queries and change the addresses as prescribed by another query that holds distinct addresses.

Comment: @sysadmin55: everybody has valid points here. ashleedawg is right: you don't need 50 different queries to do this. Darren is right that you should alias the subquery properly. But, nothing in your last comment seems to answer the question of why you need separate queries. Is there some other requirement we don't know about?